# While Loop with requestAnimtionFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im trying to make a time line drawn on a HTML5 canvas with JavaScript. I started out with a `while loop`, but it seems to malfunction within a `requestAnimationFrame` function.

An if statement works fine, but Im wondering why the while loop and requestAnimationFrame function don't work together.

This code **works**

```
var x = 50
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(50, halfway_y)
    c.lineTo(x, halfway_y)
    c.strokeStyle = "white"
    c.lineWidth = 5;
    c.stroke();
    if(x < canvas.width - 50){
        x+=7
    }

}

animate()
```

This code **doesn't work**. The code just draws the line with no animation.

```
var x = 50
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(50, halfway_y)
    c.lineTo(x, halfway_y)
    c.strokeStyle = "white"
    c.lineWidth = 5;
    c.stroke();

    while(x < canvas.width){
        x+=7
    }


}

animate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 while(x < canvas.width) {
      x+=7
 }
```

---

```
 if(x < canvas.width - 50) {
     x+=7
 }
```

The two code block is diffrent, `while` blocks let `x` to `canvas.width` at once, `if` blocks let `x` to increase only `7`.

```
x = 0
while(x < canvas.width){
     x+=7
}
console.log(x);// x = 999
```

---

```
x = 0
if(x < canvas.width - 50){
     x+=7
}
console.log(x); // x = 7
```